# PowerShell: Users not logged in for a time period ranging from 47 day

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

Any suggestions on the powershell script for the below query:

"Users not logged in for a time period ranging from 50 days to 180 days."

I know for to get for a particular time span but not for the above. :(
Thank you :)

Comment: Without any research effort or code shown this question appears to be looking for a complete code solution which is not what SO is here for. Do you have something you have tried. This is something simple that google should be able to provide a start for. After that if you have something that is not working update your question and the community should be more than happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with this command. If you really need to exclude stuff older than 180 days, try removing it from the results.

```
Search-AdAccount –accountinactive –timespan 50.00:00:00
```

I pulled that command from this post
http://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2n4o57/30_common_tasks_you_perform_using_the_gui_that/